# Starting with MassTransit

Tags: multi-tenant, masstransit

I'm already using RabbitMQ as queue 'buffer' and as messaging bus but I'm considering moving to MassTransit to make it more easy to use.

We run in a multi-tenant environment, and to isolate our tenants we have created a dedicated vhost for each tenant plus a "common" vhost for non-tenant related messages.

I would like to know if there's a Best Practice for multi-tenancy with MassTransit and if it is possible to reproduce the same schema (1 vhost per tenant) with MassTransit.

Can I create multiple instance of `IBusControl` (one per tenant linked to a dedicated `IRabbitMqHost`) in the same process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MassTransit allows the creation of as many bus instances as you need, and you could create on per vhost without any issues. Just make sure your RabbitMQ server is configured to allow enough connections/sessions to support the total number of tenants, queues, and exchanges.